# how can I capture all keypresses, including special keys such as Ctrl, Alt?

Tags: python

I tried using `getch()`  and `sys.stdin.read()`, but they only seem to capture characters, not special keys.  I'm guessing I'd need to set up some sort of GUI, and that there's no way to do it purely from the command line, but I'm not sure.  In particular, I want to be able to capture both keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for example) and individual keys such as just Ctrl by itself.  I'm on Linux (Ubuntu to be specific).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.htm) library.

[getch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch) returns an integer value for the keyboard key that was pressed.

You probably want to leverage it with the `curses.ascii` module's [ascii.ctrl()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.ascii.html#curses.ascii.ctrl) and [ascii.alt()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.ascii.html#curses.ascii.alt).

Answer (score 0):

The [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module can detect keypresses.